# if (!this) { return; } makes sense in C#?

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, destroy

I'm coding in Unity and I've found that sometimes a method can be called by an Invoke function even if the game object has been destroyed.
That's why I've added this check, and it seems to work correctly, but it's quite weird.

Let's say I have an object that I want to self destroy in one second.
I add an Invoke at the Awake to self destroy it.
But also, I want to destroy the game object instantly if the game is over. The object is subscribed to a Gameover event.

```
    void Awake ()
    {
    Invoke ("_destroy", 1);
    GameMachine.Gameover += _destroy;
    }
```

The _destroy method is like this:

```
    void _destroy()
    {
    if (!this) {
            return;
    }
    GameMachine.Gameover -= _destroy;
    Destroy (this.gameObject);
}
```

I've added that if (!this) check because I've found that the Invoke could reach the _destroy method, even if the object was already destroyed by the game over event.
This makes any sense, is it possible to happen?

Thanks

Comment: To answer the question posed in the title: `if (!this)` typically doesn't compile or make sense in C#. Unity's `Object` class, however, supports an [implicit conversion to `bool`](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object-operator_bool.html) which checks whether the object has been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks Michael Liu.  That means that if that code was in a non-MonoBehaviour class it would not even compile?

Comment: That's correct (unless of course that class supports a conversion to `bool` as well).

Comment: What a horrible use of implicit type conversions. Is there an alternative property you could look at instead (like `if(!base.destroyed)` just so that other's reading your code aren't confused?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, It will work, BUT, it's not a great idea to do so.
Unity's [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) overrides the [bool](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html) operator. Therefore, when you check

```
!this
```

you ARE checking whether the Object (and thereby the script) exists.

As a side note, if you want to unsubscribe events, use the [OnDisable](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnDisable.html) function instead. Code example

```
void OnDisable () {
    GameMachine.Gameover -= _destroy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Venkat. I think`!this` checks if the Monobehaviour exists, if the game object exists wouldn't be `!this.gameObject`? Good point with the OnDisable remark.

Comment: Yup, `!this.gameObject` does check if the GameObject exists. However, since you're invoking a function in a specific Monobehaviour, that script must exist, or the invocation will fail. So, checking for the script is the more logical way of going about this.